# Does unit testing in AngularJS involve interaction with the template?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-routing

I want to test a function that redirects to a different route. However, I'm wondering whether making the browser "click" through Karma, is putting the test out of the scope of the unit testing and making it more like e2e testing.

I saw in [Angular2 relative documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#routed-component) that it calls a "HeroClick" function, but I don't get exactly what is this function and where it comes from.

If someone can shed some light to my confused mind, I would appreciate it.

Comment: A test which interacts with the template would be an e2e test, in my opinion.

Comment: exactly, but in the Angular2 documentation, it doesn't separate things in a clear way. it just throws all kind of tests and let the user define what is actually a unit or an e2e test. 

and this is confusing for me, being new to testing.

Comment: I agree that the documentation can be difficult to use. I have to supplement with other tutorials and blogs.

Answer (score -1):

This is especially confusing because the angular documentation is not consistent with the examples provided in this case. At the top of the testing documentation there is a link "All specs that test the sample example". This includes the dashboard.compoent.spec.ts file BUT the spec provided expands on the documentation and tests the click event TWO ways. The heroClick event is checkForShallow and checkForDeep. I am a bit confused here, but it seems to be testing both clicking on the .hero and the dashboard-hero.

I have created a dashboard.compoent.spec.ts which checks only one of the click events. This is not as thorough a test, but it is consistent with the documentation. If you are interested email me and I will provide it to you.